# Import CSV file into two separate django models

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm having trouble parsing data from one csv file into two related tables in a django model.

My view.py function.

```
        for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
            _, created = User.objects.update_or_create(
                card_no=column[0],
                first_name=column[1],
                last_name=column[2],
                mobile=column[3],
                email=column[4],
                is_active=column[5]
            )

            _, created = UserPayment.objects.get_or_create(
                paid_on=column[0],
                valid_until=column[1],
                payment_status=column[2]
            )
```

This is the CSV file.
[file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhDzA.png)

How can I save the CSV data into the models without any problem?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably mistake with the column indexes look at the code below

```
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
    _, created = User.objects.update_or_create(
        card_no=column[0],
        first_name=column[1],
        last_name=column[2],
        mobile=column[3],
        email=column[4],
        is_active=column[5]
    )

    _, created = UserPayment.objects.get_or_create(
        paid_on=column[6], # column[0] is the card_no
        valid_until=column[7], # column[1] is first name
        payment_status=column[8] # column[2] is last name 
    )
```